# Photos from iPad to iCloud?

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos, photo-stream

I shoot a photo in iPad. I want it will be available in iCloud. How can I do it? I cannot see the PhotoStream in iCloud.

I can see all Pages, Numbers etc documents but not photos, I find this very confusing.

Comment: Can you better explain how did you try to access the pictures please?

Comment: @lucaghera icloud.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot view your Photo Stream pictures directly on iCloud.com. In order to do this you need to create a new Photo Stream from you iPad, iPhone or Mac (using iPhoto or Aperture).

Here's a [guide](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/shared-photo-streams-on-your-thirdgeneration-ipad.html) for doing so. In order to make it public on iCloud.com, make sure you flip the "Public Website" switch.

Comment: I did this and I added a photo to the photo-stream but I cannot find the photo in iCloud.com. Where will the photos end up?

Comment: The url is made available underneath Public Website flip switch in the user interface. It will not show up on iCloud.com directly.

Comment: Thank you, works! Had to just store the cumbersome url to bookmark -- cannot understand why Apple does this so hard, perhaps image-content-hosting is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access pictures from Safari by going www.icloud.com.

You have to enable Photo Streaming form *Settings* > *iCloud* > *Photo Stream*.

Then you will find the Photo Streaming picture under the tab *Photo Stream* in the *Photos* App.